# Less-Loader: Import URLs are being treated as relative URLs, without the --relative-url option being passed

Tags: webpack, less, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to use the less-loader to load a less file with a url import at the top. This url import is for a file that is hosted elsewhere (on a cdn).

app.less

```
@import url("http://cdn-name/mixins.less");
```

When I try to load this less file with the less-loader, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./static-content/less/app.less
Module build failed: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./http://cdn-name/mixins.less
```

It appears that the less loader is treating my url import as a relative path, instead of actually detecting that it is its own url that contains a resource to be fetched.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: ['./static-content/js/index.js'],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
    path: jsGeneratedPath,
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8444/assets/',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/js-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/json-update.json',
    recordsPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/assets/hot/')
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        progress: true
      },
      {
        test: /.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        progress: true
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: '[name].min.js'
    })
  ]
}
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? I think it **might** have something to do with the type of file I'm trying to import (a less file) because if I swap my import with a css file instead (hosted on one of google's CDNs for example) then the resolution happens fine.

I've tried with and without quotes around the url.

webpack v 1.13.1
webpack-dev-server v 1.14.1
less loader v 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same relative path issue. 
Adding Paths in option resolve it to me.

```
 {
      loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
      options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")],

      },
  }
```